# App link page with meta tags not working

Tags: ios, applinks

I have set up a web page with app link meta tags to redirect to my app or to a website. The url scheme works if I type it in the browser directly on iphone (typing myapp:// in the browser launches the app). Then I set up the following webpage:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta property="al:ios:url" content="myapp://" />
    <meta property="al:iphone:url" content="myapp://" />
    <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="My App" />
    <meta property="al:web:url" content="http://myapp.com" />
    </head>
    <body>
    Hello, world!
    </body>
</html>
```

The site just loads the page and does not launch the app or redirect to the home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those `<meta>` tags are only used by the Facebook crawler. Mobile browsers like Safari totally ignore them. You'd need to use JavaScript something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location = "https://itunes.apple.com/path/to/your/app/";
}, 25);

// If "yourapp://" is registered, your app will launch immediately and the
// timer won't fire. If not, you'll get an ugly "Cannot Open Page"
// dialogue and then the App Store will launch

window.location = "yourapp://";
```

Obviously this isn't an ideal solution, and it has a *ton* of nasty edge cases. As mentioned in [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863034/how-do-you-use-app-links-with-facebook-share-button-in-ios-to-deep-link/35867489#35867489), you'd be much happier with a service like [Branch.io](https://branch.io)

Comment: thanks, yes i am finally understanding the app links. Branch.io looks great, just can't compile with it yet

Comment: Let me know if there's anything I can do to help. Branch also has [awesome support](https://support.branch.io)!

Comment: thanks all working great now. was much easier with branch.io in the end