# Android share post to facebook with deeplink

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking

In my android app i need to share post to facebook with deeplink to my application. I have no any problems with sharing posts to facebook via Facebook SDK but i have a lot of problems with deep linking.

I read a lot of posts on stackoverflow and a lot of other themes in google but i cant make working example.

Can anyone help me with this. Maybe some code of your apps with deep linking.

Thx a lot.

Comment: Have you tried [App Links](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/android)?

Answer (score 0):

When your app is opened via a Facebook link click, you get passed a bunch of data including a URL string that you can parse out and use for deep link routing. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863034/how-do-you-use-app-links-with-facebook-share-button-in-ios-to-deep-link/35867489#35867489) for an overview of how the process works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need a website to do that. If you are mobile dev, forward this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content to web team and work with them. If you have to work by your own, let try https://branch.io/ that they covers everything for you.